# Is there a way to say getitembyid and use caml query to get no fields?

Tags: visual-web-part, caml

In my visual webpart, I want to get an item by it's id from a document library, and change it's field value. I don't want to actually read any of its field values, so I was wondering is there is a way to get an item by its id, and use a viewfields caml query to say, get this item without any fields.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [GetItemByIdSelectedFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyidselectedfields.aspx),

This method allows you to send as parameters the fields you want to receive

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You better write a proper CAML query and specify the ID field on the Where clause.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the in-built SPList method for fetching the item by it's unique ID?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyid.aspx

If it loads the default SPListItem fields it shouldn't be a concern so long as you are accessing a single item.